# Добро побеждает зло

Tags: синтаксис

Эта фраза интуитивно воспринимается так: подлежащее - "добро", сказуемое - "побеждает", а "зло" - соответственно, дополнение. Но ведь можно сделать и наоборот: "зло" - подлежащее. Сама фраза от этого не изменится, а смысл противоположный. Интонационно всего можно выделить подлежащее, чтобы смысл фразы был понятен. Но как это сделать на письме?
Я думаю, что только перестановкой слов (первое слово в предложении интуитивно воспринимается главным).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном предложении двусмысленности нет. Стилистическая закономерность такова, что на письме все косвенные падежи, кроме предложного, в начале предложения воспринимаются как именительный, а у вас "добро" действительно в именительном. Связанная с этим ошибка называется "неправильное определение падежа при омоформе (омонимичной форме)". Пример омоформы именительный/винительный: *Кислород выделяет перекись водорода.* Парадокс в том, что русская грамматика разрешает ставить дополнение на первое место, а русская стилистика это запрещает.

В вашем случае предложение корректно. Если вы хотите акцентировать "зло", это можно сделать двумя способами:

1.Зло побеждает добро.

2.Добро побеждается злом. (Вариант менее удачный, так как пассивные конструкции характерны для канцелярского стиля и используются в крайнем случае, когда порядок слов изменить нельзя.)

Answer (score 6):

Дело в том, что русский язык не аналитический, то есть связи между словами выражаются преимущественно словоизменением, которое у существительного информирует о падеже и числе, а не порядком слов и служебными словами, как, например, в английском. Если словоизменения недостаточно (или оно, как в вышеуказанном случае, затруднено по грамматическим причинам), то прибегают к интонационному выделению. С другой стороны, для русского языка все же свойственны определенные нормы построения предложения (поэтому, например, нам кажется забавной манера общения магистра Йоды: вроде понятно все, а порядок слов нелогичный), поэтому мы и воспринимаем первое слово как подлежащее, если оно формально в именительном падеже.

Теперь ближе к теме. В данном случае никак нельзя письменно указать, какое именно слово является подлежащим. Это действительно определяется "интуитивно" (хотя схема "подлежащие-сказуемое-дополнение" стандартна, так что это вряд ли интуиция), с другой стороны, появляется в некоторой степени остроумная двусмысленность.

Comment: Требуется  контекст.

Answer (score 3):

В русской грамматике порядок слов в предложении очень важен, так как он несет смысловую нагрузку. Приведенный пример - простое предложение, имеющее структуру "тема-рема". Интонационно это две фразы восходящего и нисходящего тона: "Добро (небольшая пауза,перелом интонации) побеждает зло". Тема - это "добро" (субъект действия), рема - это "побеждает зло" (словосочетание со связью управление В.п.).

Изменить семантику этого сообщения, поменяв субъект и объект местами, практически очень сложно. Это должно выглядеть примерно так: "Зло побеждает всЁ. ДобрО побеждает зло,если это добро пассивно. ЖИзнь побеждает зло, но она возрождается вновь". На словах "всё", "добро" и "жизнь" делается логическое ударение (тоническое + силовое).

Таким  образом, на письме грамматическая инверсия прочитывается из семантики всего текста.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Приведенное предложение – это  только развлекательное упражнение на грамматическую тему, в реальных текстах такой инверсированный вариант вряд ли можно встретить. Тем не менее, грамматическая инверсия  широко используется в языке, в том числе для обеспечения  выразительности текста.

В качестве примера можно рассмотреть предложение  (1) «ЖИли Артамоновы (пауза) ни с кем не знакомясь (М. Горький).  Казалось бы, зачем здесь инверсия подлежащего и сказуемого, можно  же сказать:  (2)«Артамоновы жИли  (пауза) ни с кем не знакомясь».  И тоническое ударение в обоих случаях падает на глагол «жили». Но в предложении (2) синтаксис нейтральный, невыразительный, а инверсия в предложении (1) позволяет сделать тоническое ударение силовым, логическим, а это возможно в начале предложения.

Понаблюдайте за нашей речью, и вы увидите, как часто мы меняем порядок слов в предложении, и это делается  для того, чтобы при изменении его интонационной формы обеспечить  нужные оттенки смысла,  а также сделать высказывание ярче и выразительнее.